# PHP string of zeros of random length?

Tags: php, string

How do I insert a random string of zeros (length between x and x+y) before each of the four digits for the code snipet below?

an example would be:

$quotes=array("000350.00155.062.00000044");

> ```
> <?php
>
>  $quotes=array("$random+00350.$random2+0155.$random3+062.$random4+044");
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work, I don't completely understand your array declaration however and may have missed the point.

```
$quotes = array("00350","0155","062","044");

foreach($quotes as $i => $v) {
    $a = rand($x, $x + $y);
    $zeros = "";
    for($j = 0; $j < $a; $j++) $zeros .= "0";
    $quotes[$i] = $zeros . $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would run a pseudo random over an uniform distribution [0-1]. Then, ceil of the number would be my number of zeros.

Done! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you only have the $quotes variable I would you suggest you to do this:

-> explode $quotes (using the "explode" function and puting the "." as the delimiter)

-> get a random integer from x to x+y using rand(x, x+y)

-> concatenate the parts using a loop